# Android: Proxy (Relay) Server Requests

Tags: android, proxy

I have a server and an android app. My server want to request a destination but with the IP of the android device that my app is running on. So I need to proxy the requests **(relay them)** in my app so the destination could see the client's IP but the server. You can see my explanation in the picture:

[image]

How can I do this in my app?

Comment: Have you solved this problem&

Comment: @Yarh, Not completely ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes this could be done but not just with relays; you also need to port forwarding mechanism in between. Here is how I would try to do this:

`Local portforward` the requests of the `server` onto a dedicated port on your android device and then from their call the `Destination` server via your relay mechanism which could be fulfilled very succicntly by LittleProxy like solution.